# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<EventProvider> above this CalendarWidget Widget

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, app

El error también dice: This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider of your choice.

Ocurre al utilizar la siguiente función:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_calendar/calendar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:experiments/EventEditingPage.dart';
import 'EventViewingPage.dart';
import 'package:experiments/EventProvider.dart';

class CalendarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  CalendarWidget({required this.duration, required this.stages});

  int duration;
  int stages;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final events = Provider.of<EventProvider>(context).events;

    return SfCalendar(
      view: CalendarView.week,
      firstDayOfWeek: 1,
      timeSlotViewSettings: TimeSlotViewSettings(timeInterval: Duration(minutes: duration)),
      dataSource: EventDataSource(events),
      onTap: (CalendarTapDetails details) {
        if (details.appointments == null) {
          //final provider = Provider.of<EventProvider>(context, listen: false);
          //provider.setDate(details.date!);
          final event = Event(from: details.date!, to: details.date!.add(Duration(minutes: duration)), duration: duration, stage: stages);
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EventEditingPage(event: event),));

        } else {
          final event = details.appointments!.first;

          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EventViewingPage(event: event),));
        }


      },
    );
  }

}
```

Falla en la línea de final events = ... Provider está importada y EventProvider es:

```
class EventProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Event> _events = [];

  List<Event> get events => _events;

  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  DateTime get selectedDate => _selectedDate;

  void setDate(DateTime date) => _selectedDate = date;

  List<Event> get eventsOfSelectedDate => _events;

  void addEvent(Event event) {
    _events.add(event);

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deleteEvent(Event event) {
    _events.remove(event);

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void editEvent(Event newEvent, Event oldEvent) {
    final index = _events.indexOf(oldEvent);
    _events[index] = newEvent;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Event es:

```
class Event {
  final DateTime from;
  final DateTime to;
  final int duration;
  final int stage;

  const Event({
    required this.from,
    required this.to,
    required this.duration,
    required this.stage,
  });
}
```

He seguido el tutorial de https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoDtxRkGDTw&t=1809s y el código es el mismo, pero aquí por algún motivo no funciona. He visto el mismo error que ya ha sido preguntado alguna vez, pero las soluciones no me han servido. Alguien sabe qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: significa que el EventProvider no está encima del arbol de widgets que estás usando en el momento

Comment: @diegoveloper Eso en código qué significa? Qué tendría que cambiar?

Comment: según el código que agregaste no se puede identificar el error, porque no estás poniendo el código donde agregas el provider

Comment: @diegoveloper He añadido la clase en la que uso Provider. Esa clase la uso en la página principal de la app en la que escribo CalendarWidget con los parámetros que necesita para mostrar el calendario.  Puede estar el error en esta parte?

Comment: En que momento registras el Provider ? y en que momento llamas a CalendarWidget